# How to convert jQuery's indexOf to InArray

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where I have to setup a conditional to detect IE8.  I would like to convert the below process...

```
if(['About', 'Join', 'Participate','Support','Media Center','Error 404'].indexOf(msubpagetitle) == -1) {
            //do custom jquery actions
        }
```

...to a jQuery.inArray() condition.  How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to convert this... seems very...backwards.

Comment: Because it breaks in IE8, and I need to support that browser with this condition.

Comment: Ahh, nvm, makes sense.

Comment: I'm still going to use this, but also need a condition for IE8...thats all.

Comment: `$.inArray(msubpagetitle, ['About', 'Join', 'Participate','Support','Media Center','Error 404'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($.inArray( msubpagetitle,['About', 'Join', 'Participate','Support','Media Center','Error 404'])!=-1);
```

The [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf() method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.

Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0 !== false), to check for the presence of value within array, you need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1.